# Ideal Op Amp model in PSpice capture

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, pspice

I am trying to simulate a comparator in pspice capture student version. The problem that I am facing is that circuit is not working for higher frequencies because the opamp I am using is not ideal.

I downloaded `opamp.olb` and `opamp.lib` from this link http://robustdesignconcepts.com/files/pspice/pmindex.htm  and tried many opamp modals from this library.

I have searched some other libraries from this page too but I cant find an ideal opamp modal.

Can anyone share any pspice libraries which has ideal opamp or guide me how to build one.

Answer (score 1):

I am using also PSpice - however with a schematic entry package called "SCHEMATICS". In this library there is a part called "opamp" which is the model of an ideal opamp without any frequency-dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back. What **is** an opamp ?

You want an ideal opamp yet you search for models of **real** opamps which (assuming the model is any good) include **non ideal** properties.

The same **non ideal** properties (like bandwidth) you're trying to get rid of !?!?!

See the contradiction ?

Now back to my question, what actually **is** an opamp. What would be the behavour of an **ideal** opamp ?

In literature you can find:

$$V_{out} = A * (V_{in+} - V_{in-})$$

where \$V_{in+}\$ and \$V_{in-}\$ are the voltages at the non-inverting and inverting inputs of the opamp. And \$V_{out}\$ is the output voltage obviously. A is the gain which we often want to be as high as possible.

Now how would one make this in a simulator ? That is actually quite easy, the **Voltage controlled Voltage source** does just that. You can set the gain as high as you like but in practice, start with 1000 and see how that goes. A higher gain might confuse the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate it using a voltage controlled voltage source vcvs or a voltage controlled current source vccs followed by an output resistance.

The two-port equivalent circuit of an OpAmp will help you understand it better since it is a simple representation of what is really happening in a differential amplifier (OpAmp is basically composed by a diff.amp and a common drain). The pair of transistors convert the differential input voltage into current by a factor of "gm" and then this current flows through an equivalent output resistance, causing a voltage drop (output voltage)